# Reverse JSTL for each loop for year (using dropdown)

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, jstl

I want to create a dropdown menu that starts with the current year, or at least starts with 2016 and ends with 1900

I only have this code right mow but is not working properly.

```
    <select id="year" name="year">
        <c:forEach begin="1900" end="2016" var="val">
            <c:set var="decr" value="${2016-val}"/>
            <option value="${decr}" ${birthYear == decr ? 'selected' : ''}>${decr}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<select id="year" name="year">
            <c:forEach begin="0" end="116" var="val">
                <c:set var="decr" value="${2016 - val}"/>
                <option value="${decr}" ${birthYear == decr ? "selected='selected'": ''}>${decr}</option>
            </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: You are awesome! Worked perfectly for me! Good job! :)

Comment: Thank you, Edward.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using dynamically loaded `current year`.

Add at the top of your jsp file the following, in order to load the fmt taglib

```
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Then using the following commands, you create a variable named `year` having the value of the current year.

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate var="year" value="${now}" pattern="yyyy" />
```

Finally, use this value, in order to create your desired `select` options in a more effective way.

```
<select id="year" name="year">
    <c:forEach begin="0" end="${year-1900}" var="age">
        <option value="${age}" ${birthYear == age ? "selected='selected'": ""}>${age}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```